# Where does Nautilus get the icons for SSH mounts?

Tags: ssh, nautilus, icons

I am running Nautilus 3.4.2 on Ubuntu 12.04. I spend a lot of my time working on files and in folders accessed over SSH, which I connect to by putting `sftp://wherever.my.domain/home/myuser/folder` in my Nautilus URL bar, and bookmarking the folder with `Ctrl+D` for easy access.

When I connect to one of these folders over SSH, on one particular server (running CentOS release 6.6 (Final)), I get this:
[image: screenshot showing centos icon]

That's a CentOS logo showing up in my Nautilus, on Ubuntu. None of the other systems I connect to have cool favicons like that; they all show the folder-with-network-jack icon that's used over on the left in the bookmarks. Where did Nautilus get this icon? Is it detecting the OS of the remote host? Is there some kind of SSH favicon standard that I don't know about? Can I set icons for my other systems that I access?